# Prevent Workflow from Breaking Item Permission Inheritance

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, permissions, inheritance

I'm growing increasingly frustrated at an apparent design flaw in SharePoint 2010. I have created a workflow (happens in both List and Reusable types) that has several vanilla Approval Processes within it. Each time I create a new item in my custom list and start the workflow, it breaks inheritance on the list item for each Approval step.

There appears to be a number of broken inheritances for any given item, equal to the number of Approval Processes that particular item went through. This leads me to believe that something inherent within the Approval Process is actually breaking the inheritance. I have tried adding an Inherit list permissions action (within an Impersonation step run as an Admin user) to workaround this, but even that is not working now.

[image]

After three approval steps, I get the following:

[image]

What the crap is going on? I'm sorry, but I'm losing my mind over this problem!